# Include day in the date format

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataset which has only Year and Month as seperate columns(aand not the day). I am using this code to combine these in one column and make a date series. Later, I want to convert this table to a time series. But it's not functioning properly.

```
df$date <- as.yearmon(paste(df$year,df$Month, 1, sep = "-"))
```

The Output is this:

```
> head(df$date)
[1] "Jan 2014" "Feb 2014" "Mrz 2014" "Apr 2014" "Mai 2014" "Jun 2014"
```

Please help me with a function that can include day part of the date as well. The day for each month is 1. So the output should be in date format as:

```
1-1-2014 1-2-2014 1-3-2014 1-4-2014 1-5-2014 1-6-2014
```

Also, to convert a "tbl" to ts class, is it necessary that the date has to be in a particular Format?

Please note: I want to extract the date from the original dataset because some of my variables have missing dates and i want to identify them so that the correponding values can be handles accordingly.

Comment: Try `as.Date(paste(df$year,df$Month, 1, sep = "-"))` instead. If not working, then share a reproducible example of your data.

Comment: Hey, thanks! This works!

Answer (score 0):

using lubridate you can do it

```
df <-read.table(text="year  month
2019    january
2019    february
2019    march
2019    april
2019    may
2019    june
2019    july
2019    august
2019    september
2019    october
2019    november
2019    december
",header = T)

str(df)

library(lubridate)
df$date <-dmy(paste0(01,"-",df$month,"-",df$year))
```

Comment: Hey,on using this function I am getting the following error: `Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘stringr’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘lubridate’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lubridate’`

Comment: you need to install lubridate with all its dependencies including stringr

Comment: I am trying to install Lubridate

Comment: you need to install lubridate along with stringr and Rcpp